# Detectar inactividad del usuario incluso si destruyo la aplicación

Tags: android

Buen día, he implementado un código para detectar la inactividad del usuario y hasta el momento funciona muy bien para prueba he puesto solo un minuto de inactividad tras pasar el minuto se ejecuta una consulta que libera el cupo que el usuario inactivo acaba de ocupar, entonces hasta aquí todo bien pero como puedo hacer para que el cupo también se libere si la aplicación es destruida y pase el minuto de inactividad? solo me funciona si dejo la aplicación en segundo plano pero no si la elimino por completo!

```
//Variables

private long startTime=1*60*1000; // 15 MINS IDLE TIME
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;

//Inicializo mi contador cuando la actividad se crea

countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);

//Implementacion

 @Override
public void onUserInteraction(){

    super.onUserInteraction();

    //Reinicia el tiempo cada vez que el usuario interactua con la actividad
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    countDownTimer.start();
}

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        
        // Ejecuto mi código al pasar el minuto de inactividad

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    }
}
```

Entonces como mencionaba esto funciona muy bien pero también necesito que funcione cuando la aplicación no solo este en segundo plano si no también sea destruida, investigando un poco encontré un código que se ejecutaba antes de que la aplicación sea destruida pero no me ha funcionado probablemente lo he implementado mal y el uso es un **onFinishing**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finalizo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}
```

Espero me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Usar  isFinishing() dentro de onPause() sería buena opción.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En realidad no puedes saber cuando la aplicación va a ser destruida, pero puedes determinarlo cuando tu Activity principal va a cerrarse.

Para saber cuando tu Activity va a ser destruida puedes revisar el ciclo de vida de la misma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por lo tanto cuando se llama `onStop()` es cuando la Activity esta marcada para ser destruida, aquí podrías saber cuando va a terminar tu activity principal y por lo tanto tu app.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
        // La Activity se destuira.
}
```

Otro método para saber cuando se terminará la Activity principal es precisamente usando `isFinishing()` pero en `onPause()`, de esta forma puedes detectar cuando la activity finalizará:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        // La activity será destruida eventualmente.
    }
}
```

---

No es recomendable usar `onDestroy()` para conocer cuando termina una Activity ya que no podrás llamar procesos antes del cierre de la Activity, incluso si tratas de mostrar un `Toast`, este no funcionaría adecuadamente ya que el contexto se pierde.

Answer (score 0):

Ponlo tambien en el Ondestroy:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (isFinishing()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Finalizo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
    }
}
```